# When to use qemu user mode versus system mode?

Tags: firmware, embedded, qemu, emulation

This seems to be a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find a good answer.

I am currently just following https://w00tsec.blogspot.ca/2013/09/analyzing-and-running-binaries-from.html to learn more about emulating with qemu.

Whats the advantages and disadvantages between:

```
sudo chroot . ./qemu-mips-static bin/busybox (example)
```

compared to following the instructions found here: https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/

```
qemu-system-mips -M malta kernel
```

Thanks in advance!